# How can I break up text with whitespace but also if it's too long?

Tags: javascript, css

So I think I have a bit of a dilemma.

I have a grid that with fixed width columns but not fixed width rows.

So, I have a scenario like here

```
Column1, row 1: 
ThisisalongtextstringthatdoesnotcontainspacesthatIneedtobreakup

Column2, row2:
This is a long text string that has whitespace and I would like to cut based on whitespace between words.
```

Here's my attempts to making these strings lookg alright in my grid:

```
.k-grid td {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
    padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```

The above solution breaks up the second string using whitespace and restricting it to the column width which makes the string look readable.

However the above snippet also does not break up the long string above.

I used using `word-break: break-all;` which is also great (since the string first is broken up and doesn't run into the other columns) but with the second string, it break ups like word something like below (which I don't want):

Break-all does this to whitespace words:

```
This is a long first name wit
h
```

So that the h is hanging off but I would prefer to have the with on the second line.

So, I'm wondering how can I deal with both problems?

Comment: have you tried text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow:hidden ?

Comment: I don't want ellipsis, I want to show everything in the grid. I tried an ellipsis approach and it very buggy/isn't working with my grid. This is sadly my backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `word-wrap: break-word;` :

[**From MDN's docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)

> **break-word**
>   Indicates that normally unbreakable words may be broken at arbitrary points if there are no otherwise acceptable break points in the line.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid silver;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  ThisisalongtextstringthatdoesnotcontainspacesthatIneedtobreakup
</div>
<div>
  This is a long text string that has whitespace and I would like to cut based on whitespace between words.
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much! I didn't know about word-wrap and break-word.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is `word-wrap: break-word;`

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z0Lrtcfr/)

Comment: Yup, exactly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `break-word`:

```
word-break:break-word;
-webkit-hyphens:auto;
-moz-hyphens:auto;
hyphens:auto;
```

The hyphens are fallbacks.

If you wanted to break every single letter to a new line, rather than by word, you can use `word-break:break-all;`.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xq1xsrvs/3/)

Inspired by [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

Comment: Strangely enough I needed word-wrap:break-word; instead of word-break:break-word; . Thanks for the CSS Tricks link, I like how they consider hyphens

Comment: You're welcome - i've used this approach in projects that needed to support IE7+, it worked great.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue with my own development and was unable to find a CSS solution that worked consistently with the browsers that the site needed to support. The other answers suggest using `word-break: break-word`, which will work well in some modern browsers, but some browsers interpret this the same as `word-break: break-all`.

I presume that you are using server-side code to create the table. One way to accommodate older browsers is to break up long words by inserting a zero-width space (&#8203;), giving those older browsers a clue where long words can be broken. When receiving the text, my code would find words longer than 20 characters and break the word into 20-character portions with the zero-width space.